# Save DataTable into specific location (Dash - Python)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am able to download changes made in a datatable that is visualised using Dash (plotly). However I would like to download the datatable into a specific location onto the server it currently runs on.

Code and call back: -

```
 html.Div([
               html.Div([
               # Add table
                dash_table.DataTable(
                 id= 'ElecSysparts_table',
                 data= df.to_dict('records'),
                 columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                 page_action='none',
                 style_table={'height': '600px', 'overflowX': 'auto','overflowY': 'auto'},
                 editable=True,
                 # row_deletable=True,
                 filter_action='native',
                 sort_action="native",
                 fixed_rows={
                 "headers": True,
                 },
                 style_header={
                 'backgroundColor': 'rgb(210, 230, 230)',
                 'color': 'black',
                 'fontWeight': 'bold'
                 },
                 style_data={
                 'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                 'height': 'auto'},
                 style_cell={
                     'minWidth': '180px', 'width': '180px', 'maxWidth': '180px',
                     'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                     'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
                     'overflow': 'hidden'
                     },
                 export_format="csv"
                 ),
                 html.Button("Save Changes onto Server", id='changes_xlsx'),
                 dcc.Download(id='download-ElecSysdf-xlsx')], 
                   style = {'margin-top': '20px','width':'50%','display': 'inline-block'}),
                html.Div([
                # Add pie chart    
                    dcc.Graph(id='ElecSys_graph')
                    ], style = {'margin-top': '20px','width':'50%','display': 'inline-block'}),
                    ],
                    style={'display':'flex'}), 

@app.callback(
    Output("download-ElecSysdf-xlsx","data"),
    Input("changes_xlsx","n_clicks"),
    [State("ElecSysparts_table", "data")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
    )
def download_DataTable(n_clicks,data):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
    path = r"E:\TeamCenter\New folder"
    return dcc.send_data_frame(df.to_csv(path, index=False),'Purchased_parts_Electrical_Systems.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, use_reloader=False,
                   # host = 'Example',
                   host = "x.x.x.x", 
                   port="****")
```

Currently the datatable downloads on any device when the user clicks on the button, I would like that to change and saves onto the specified path in the server where dash is currently run from.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dcc_store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) and [persistence](https://dash.plotly.com/persistence) this should help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).